# How to copy a struct from a pointer-to-void?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Say I have a DLL contains a struct, but I don't know the details of this struct. But I have a void pointer which points to address of the struct.

Can anybody tell me how can I get the details of the struct? Such as output the struct to a text file.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't, without having the `struct`'s definition. I.e., the appropriate header file.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find the corresponding header file.

Comment: It should be noted that APIs typically use void pointers specifically when they *don't* want people knowing the details of what their data is -- that way they can change their data-layout in the future without breaking anyone's code.  So defeating the intent of the API author may be a bad idea here, in that it may bite you in the future when implementation details change and your program (which is now depending on those details *not* changing) breaks.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot know the details of the struct without the type definition. Copying a region starting with the void pointer without a type definition will give you the raw binary data, but you wont know where it ends, or which pieces represent which variables. Some of the values could be integer values or they could be pointer addresses. There are all sorts of possibilities.

You should try to obtain the header file.

You *might* be able to glean some information from the debug / symbol file if you have it (example .pdb files on Windows), or debugging the program with GDB on Linux, this will only work if you have a debug build of the program. Refer to the "whatis" and "ptype" commands in GDB.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find the corresponding header file.

Comment: Since it's tagged C++, you also have to consider inheritance. Even if you knew the `void*` really should have been a `Base*`, the possibility still exists that at runtime it points to a `Derived*`. Also, copying all bits in a C++ class isn't guaranteed to work. A common class where that fails is `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You never know this without structure definition. Also there can be "holes" between the user's variables in the real memory placement because of the alignment and padding.

Say if you have,

```
struct mystr {
    char x;
    int y;
};
```

by default such structure  most likely will have size 8, and after one byte of `char x` there will be three bytes of padding (in theory random values), and then 4 bytes of `int y`, but it depends on compiler and its directives.